# Why Principal is not a model, but Role, RoleMapping, ACL are suddenly models?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm reading Access control concepts of Loopback (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Authentication%2C+authorization%2C+and+permissions) and I don't understand how happened that `Principal` is not a model, but `Role`, `RoleMapping`, `ACL` are models with a full set of REST API methods and are listed in `model-config.json`? When I tried to include `Principal` in `model-config.json` along with `Role`, `RoleMapping` and `ACL` I got error:

```
"ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
},
"RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
},
"Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
},
"Principal": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
},
```

Error:

```
throw new Error('Model not found: ' + modelName);
      ^
Error: Model not found: Principal
```

Where is logic here? `Principal` is in one line with others but isn't a model. Why?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. Wanted to ask myself.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first make it clear, what a principal is?

As per the documentation, *Principal is an entity that can be identified or authenticated. It represents identities of a request to protected resources*. For example: an `user` instance can be authenticated to execute a `create` request. Therefore, that `user` instance can be a principal.

If we can use `user`, `application` or `role` in place of principal, it doesn't make sense to make another model in **core loopback**.

But if you see [Class Principal](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#principal) as per the documentation,

*This class represents the abstract notion of a principal, which can be used to represent any entity, such as an individual, a corporation, and a login id*. This class have three attributes: type, id and name. This `type` field specifies which model is being used for principal. `principal` class instance can be created in many ways. For example, for `role` model instance as in

```
role.principals.create({
    principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.USER,
    principalId: admin.id
}, function(err, principal) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Here, we created new `principal` instance for a `role` instance. Now this principal can be used to authenticate a request. Also, notice `principalType` is used to define which model is being used to create a principal.

**Note:**
I hope, now, it make sense that *`principal` uses other model instances that can be uniquely identified and thus, can be used to authenticate requests to protected resources like a `create` rest endpoint.*

Now the error you received is because there is no model defined as `Principal`. And while bootstrapping the app, it didn't found the `Principal` model in either Loopback core models or generated model for our app so it threw the error

```
throw new Error('Model not found: ' + modelName);
      ^
Error: Model not found: Principal
```

Comment: But I can't figure out how an application can be a principal. Nice explanation though. Thanks!

Comment: It is already discussed here: github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/issues/31 . Well till we get an example from the maintainers, it was there to authorize other application to access loopback api. It would be like application-level authorization