# What the heck is principals in loopback and how to create role with it

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I trying simple example from [loopback doc](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-default-admin-user.html), already read [Why Principal is not a model, but Role, RoleMapping, ACL are suddenly models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541933/why-principal-is-not-a-model-but-role-rolemapping-acl-are-suddenly-models)
 But still can't understand from where exactly *principals* come from. I searched all loopback code and still, can't find it. All I can say *principals* is some kind of abstraction.

And back to the code:

```
  module.exports = function(create) {
    create.models.User.create([{email: '', password: ''},
  {email: '', password: ''}], function(users) {;
  create.models.Role.create({name: 'Product'}, function(product) {;
  product.principals.create({ principalType: create.models.RoleMapping.USER, principalId: users[1].id}, function(mainproduct) {;
  });
    });
  });
  };
```

Node on start gives `TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` for *principals*, and I have no idea what to define for *principals*

AI, human or vice principals, please reply!

Comment: `function(mainproduct) {;` you have a typo here and above+.....?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to make code work, and this avoids using cb, and didn't stops node from running.

```
module.exports = function(create) {
    create.models.User.create([{email: '', password: ''},
  {email: '', password: ''}], function(err, users) { console.log(err, users);
  create.models.Role.create({name: 'Product'}, function(err, product) { console.log(err, product);
  product.principals.create({ principalType: create.models.RoleMapping.USER, principalId: users[1].id}, function(err, mainproduct) { console.log(err, mainproduct);
  });
    });
  });
  };
```

However, its still not obvious where from *principals* come from. However it works indeed.